# how to connect two datagridview using ther ID

Tags: c#

I created two tables which is book and author in wamp server,
I would like to know how can I connect two datagridview using their ID. 
example: if i selected a book details from bookdatagridview with authorid to the last column. base on the authorid from the book selected the author of the certain book should be displayed to the authordatagridview beside bookdatagridview.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey(v=vs.110).aspx) link :

Create a relation in `DataSet` & use `BindingSource` to bind them :

```
 private DataGridView masterDataGridView = new DataGridView();
    private BindingSource masterBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    private DataGridView detailsDataGridView = new DataGridView();
    private BindingSource detailsBindingSource = new BindingSource();

private void GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
            // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample
            // database accessible to your system.
            String connectionString =
                "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" +
                "Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            // Create a DataSet.
            DataSet data = new DataSet();
            data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            // Add data from the Customers table to the DataSet.
            SqlDataAdapter masterDataAdapter = new
                SqlDataAdapter("select * from Customers", connection);
            masterDataAdapter.Fill(data, "Customers");

            // Add data from the Orders table to the DataSet.
            SqlDataAdapter detailsDataAdapter = new
                SqlDataAdapter("select * from Orders", connection);
            detailsDataAdapter.Fill(data, "Orders");

            // Establish a relationship between the two tables.
            DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("CustomersOrders",
                data.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerID"],
                data.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"]);
            data.Relations.Add(relation);

            // Bind the master data connector to the Customers table.
            masterBindingSource.DataSource = data;
            masterBindingSource.DataMember = "Customers";

            // Bind the details data connector to the master data connector,
            // using the DataRelation name to filter the information in the 
            // details table based on the current row in the master table. 
            detailsBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
            detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "CustomersOrders";
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("To run this example, replace the value of the " +
                "connectionString variable with a connection string that is " +
                "valid for your system.");
        }
    }
```